# run release tasks selectively based on project code changes

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, winrm

We are using VSTS for build and release management, and using CI/CD. Typically, our solutions consist of a web application project, and a database project.

Our current release tasks take the application offline (using app_offline.htm), publish the database, then publish the web application. Publishing the database project often results in no changes, as due to CI/CD we are much more frequently updating code on the web app than changing the db schema.

Is there a way to only run the database publish task (using WinRM) when it detects a change in the database project code, in our git repository?

**EDIT:** This in itself isn't a problem, as typically when the DACPAC gets published, there will be no activity. HOWEVER, I've been requesting that the database is backed up using the **/p:BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges=true** flag - which seems to back up the database even if there are no changes. This is an issue for large databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - exactly what I want isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is that you can separate web project and database project to two build definitions.

1. Create a new build definition
2. Enable Continuous Integration in Triggers tab
3. Specify Path filter to include database project
4. Modify Visual Studio Build task, specify `/t:[database project name]` argument in **MSBuild Arguments** box to just build database project
5. The same steps for web project
6. Create a new related definition
7. Add artifacts for previous two build definitions and enable Continuous deployment trigger
8. Add two environments (e.g. database, web)
9. Open Pre-deployment conditions of an environment (e.g. database)
10. Enable Artifact filters and select corresponding artifact (e.g. database build artifact), specify build branch (can specify `*`, it means all branches)
11. Add tasks to just deploy database in this environment
12. The same steps for web environment

Comment: This is good.. except when I release, I apply a nice "app offline" file on the web app, so the users know changes are being made. If make changes to both projects and commit, both builds and releases will kick off but I won't be able to assume that when the web project is deployed that it's safe to remove the 'app offline' file, as the db project may still be deploying. Is there another way?

Comment: @benpage Add [Azure App service management task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceManage) in database environment to stop app service before deploy database and start again after deploying.

Comment: I'm not using Azure Apps. I'm using windows servers.

Comment: Using [IIS Web App Manage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage) to stop web site.

Comment: OK I think there's some misunderstanding. I don't want to stop the web site. I want to display the app_offline.htm file. Which I can do. However, regardless of how I do it, the issue remains, that if I am using two releases that run simultaneously, there's no way of determining when BOTH are complete. Is there a solution where I can just use one release and filter my release tasks or something?

Comment: It is hard to deal the concurrency issue, stop the website is the easy way to deal it. Since the database project won't be updated frequently, you can queue database build manually (disable CI) at specific time to deploy database. (pause web build first and check there aren't related build and release running) Note: If the build definition is paused, then all builds will not start until resume this build definition.